# PhysX - Revolute joint around unit vector

Tags: physics, rotation, physx, axis

I'm using a right-handed coordinate system with `(0,0,-1) = forward`, `(1,0,0) = right` and `(0,1,0) = up`. PhysX version is 3.3.0.

I have a unit vector which represents the axis around which my actor is supposed to be able to rotate, `(0,1,0)`.

The problem is, if I build a quaternion rotation from that vector, like so:

```
physx::PxQuat q = (0, physx::PxVec3(0, 1, 0));
```

and use that for the joint, the actor will actually rotate around the direction of the rotation around the axis:

http://youtu.be/pXMlRRBVOpc

However, what I want is this:

http://youtu.be/MlBx-hC1Z9Q

In the second case I used `(0,0,1)` as axis and 90 degree as rotation and used that to build the quaternion.

So, how can I use my axis `(0,1,0)` and actually get the rotation as shown in the second video?